# Facebook iOs SDK - post a pre-filled message on users' wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I've just read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

It says since the 12th of July 2011 it is not possible anymore to use the "message" property to prefill a message to post on users wall e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"hi!", @"message", nil]; 
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]
```

Can anybody please explain what is the official plan B?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195917/fill-in-message-box-on-facebook-mobile-app/7196236#7196236).

Comment: Ok, so the answer is "don't do it" fine. But then why does it say _"your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow"_? What is that workflow? Do I need to create it myself with my own Views then use the graph api like Adam suggested (which will "cost" me an extra permission)?

Comment: This is just speculation on my part, but it would seem like it used to be allowed under those conditions in the policy, but since people didn't follow it, they decided to disable it completely. My guess is that the policy has simply not been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> If you would like your application to publish directly to a profile's feed without user interaction, use the corresponding [Graph API call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#publishing).

However, note that you need to ask for the `publish_stream` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) in order to be able to post to a user's wall.

Comment: Ok, but then it won't display the nice Facebook popup users are used to see will it? And if possible I would like to keep the number of requested permission to the bare minimum...

Comment: It's against policy to prefill that parameter unless the user gave you the text earlier in a workflow. If they gave you the text earlier in the workflow, you can do what Adam suggested and post directly to the Graph API. If you want some prefilled content you should add this elsewhere in the post

Comment: That's the concept of workflow I'm having a hard time to understand. Who manages/creates it? Me? FB? What is the end-user's visual experience?

Comment: It depends on the text you're trying to prefill and why you want to prefill it. In most cases i've seen this prefilled, it's had some obviously inauthentic text like 'I just did <something> in an app!' as the message paramater on a post which had basically the same content (e.g 'shared a link via...' 'completed the X quest...). Short version: message parameter = something the user said themselves, rest of post = the 'thing' your app wants to share

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So basically I have 2 options right? 
**1 -** use the `[Facebook dialog: andParams:]` function, let the user write whatever message they want and put my app message in the _caption_ and _description_ parameters. 
Or **2 -** do my own popup where I write the message for the users and let them check/modify before they press my own "post" button, all this using a graph api call, but needing an extra permission? 
Am I correct? Is this the "workflow" you were talking about?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to posting a pre populated message? My app will post something the user typed in at a different time to save.. so posting it and not having them retype it is crucial and I am finding now help... pleaseeee

Comment: Yes I have the same issue, does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"message", @"hi!", nil]; 

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

exchange your object with key....this is right:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"hi", @"message", nil];
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the question (now edited). You're right in principle but the point is this has now been deprecated.