# Fill in message box on facebook mobile app

Tags: facebook, mobile

Very simply I want to fill in the message box that is generated by this page: http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed. The user has given stream publish permissions and chosen options to fill in the text on my site. Using `?message=xxx` has apparently been deprecated.

How do I fill in this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/):

> **Breaking Change: "message" parameter ignored in Feed Dialog**
>
> On July 12, we are ignoring the message parameter in Feed Dialogs. This eliminates the ability to pre-fill stream stories (prohibited by [Policy IV.2](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)). This change encourages users to share authentic and relevant content with their friends.

So this is a deliberate change and you should not attempt to bypass it.

Comment: how do applications such as Cityville  etc. post to users walls?

Comment: also, I guess my question is why have users login to facebook at all if I can't post their activity to their walls when they've granted that permission?